# Expected value of the intersection of two standard normal distribution half-sapce

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, geometry, statistics, numerical-linear-algebra

for a random variable $x \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_{d})$, I want to calculate (or to find an upper \a lower bound) of this term $$\mathbb E\bigl[f(b_{k}^{\top}x)f(b_{i}^{\top}x)\bigr]$$ where $f(x)=\max(0,x)$ and $k,i \in \{1,\dots,q\}$ for $q \in (20,\infty)$ . In this way, we might consider this term as the integral over intersection of two half-spaces. And also we know $||b_{i}||_{1}=c \in (0,\infty)$ and $||b_{i}||_{2}^{2}=1$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{q\times d}$ where $d \in [1,\infty)$. And we also know the value of $$\int _{\substack{b_k^{\top} x> 0  \\
 b_i^{\top} x> 0}}p(x)~dx = l \text{   for } l \in (0,1)$$.
Accordingly, I have used 1. the difinition of function $f$, 2. : some rewriting and 3. extracting $b_{k}^{\top}, b_{i}$ from both sides to obtain
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\bigl[f(b_{k}^{\top}x)f(b_{i}^{\top}x)\bigr] &= \int_{\substack{b_k^{\top} x> 0  \\
 b_i^{\top} x> 0}}b_{k}^{\top}xb_{i}^{\top}x~ p(x)~dx\\
&= \int_{\substack{b_k^{\top} x> 0  \\
 b_i^{\top} x> 0}}b_{k}^{\top}x x^{\top}b_{i}~ p(x)~dx\\
&= b_{k}^{\top}\int_{\substack{b_k^{\top} x> 0  \\
 b_i^{\top} x> 0}}xx^{\top}~ p(x)~dx~b_{i}\\
\end{align}

but it is wrong and not complete. I would be so thankful if you could please help me regarding this and share your ideas to solve it. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong in the first equation. You have two nested parentheses around the same expression, and you seem to be taking the transpose of a number.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited it.

Comment: I still don't understand it. $b_i^\top x$ is a number, and $f(x)=\max(0,x)$, so $f(x)$ is a number – so what does it mean to take the transpose of $f(b_i^\top x)$?

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. Does it make sense now?

Comment: The first equation seems to make sense now. In the second one, you seem to be saying that an integral over the probability density is an integer $k\ge20$? The probability density is normalized to $1$, so that can't be right.

Comment: it was typo sorry.

Comment: By the way, you can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a coordinate system where $b_i$ and $b_k$ lie in the $x_1$-$x_2$ plane. Then, since the integrand doesn’t depend on the remaining coordinates and the coordinates are independent variables, we can integrate out all the remaining coordinates. Transform the $x_1$-$x_2$ plane to polar coordinates $r,\phi$ and choose $\phi$ such that $b_i^\top x=r\sin\phi$ and $b_k^\top x=r\sin(\phi+\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between $b_i$ and $b_k$. Then the desired expectation is

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi-\alpha}\sin\phi\sin(\phi+\alpha)r^2\mathrm e^{-\frac{r^2}2}\mathrm d\phi\,r\mathrm dr}{\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm e^{-\frac{r^2}2}\mathrm d\phi\,r\mathrm dr}
&=&
\frac{\int_0^\infty r^3\mathrm e^{-\frac{r^2}2}\mathrm dr\int_0^{2\pi-\alpha}\sin\phi\sin(\phi+\alpha)\mathrm d\phi}{2\pi}
\\
&=&
\frac1{2\pi}\left(\sin\alpha+(\pi-\alpha)\cos\alpha\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This means that $\mathbb P[b_i^x > 0,b_k^Tx>0]=\mathbb E[f(b_i^Tx)f(b_k^Tx)]$, right ? Therefore in the setup of OP, the expectation is actually exactly $l$.

Comment: @P.Quinton: I'm sorry, I was only integrating over the probability. I've corrected the answer – I hope it's OK now?

Comment: Is the $r^3$ in the integral over $r$ a typo ?

Comment: @P.Quinton: No – it's $r^2$ from the integrand and $r$ from the Jacobian of the polar coordinates. (I wrote them separately on the left-hand side.)

Comment: Right my bad, looks good to me then.

Comment: Do you mean $$\int _{\substack{b_k^{\top} x> 0  \\
 b_i^{\top} x> 0}}p(x)~dx =\int_{\substack{b_k^{\top} x> 0  \\
 b_i^{\top} x> 0}}b_{k}^{\top}xb_{i}^{\top}x~ p(x)~dx$$

In my intuition $$p(b_k^{\top}x \cap b_j^{\top}x )=\int _{\substack{b_k^{\top} x> 0  \\
 b_i^{\top} x> 0}}p(x)~dx$$

means "joint probability density function of two correlated standard normal random variables", am I right?

Comment: @Raha: I'm afraid I don't understand. Which part of my answer are you referring to? The first equation you wrote seems wrong to me – how did you derive it? The second one doesn't seem to make any sense – how do you define the intersection of two numbers on the left-hand side? (By the way, you double-posted your comment – you might want to delete the first copy to reduce the clutter.)

Comment: @ 
joriki
, no my question is about P.Quinton's comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Raha: I was notified because this is my answer. P.Quinton will only get notified if you include a ping (`@P.Quinton`) in your comment. Don't include a space like you did in pinging me – I don't think that works.